# Sort datagridview by recently updated rows

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sorting

is it possibble to SORT data gridview in a way that it displays latest updated row first ?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. if you have a column in table that records when the row was update you can just sort by this row.